# What is the regular expression for the machine shown?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, finite-automata, state-diagram

I'm wrestling with the problem and got 0*1+(00 U 01)* as the regular expression for the language that describes this machine. Is this correct? Or is there a better/simpler answer? [image: state diagram]

Comment: What do you mean by `U`? That is not a regex operator I am aware of and it does not seem to be covered by the shown diagram. Please state the regex flavor you are targeting, maybe there is one with that operator. Otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially the part starting with "Post the question and respond to feedback". It seems that you asked a question and left for 10 hours (and counting). Please do not do that.

Answer (score 2):

q2 on 1 to q2 can be repeated in between 00 and 01 also
   10011101  not covered in your answer, one possible answer is

```
  0*1(1|00|01)*
```

Comment: Which regex flavor would match the inputs you name with the regex you propose? I am not aware of any with the `U` operator. I also think that any implementation would expect the blanks ` ` to be part of the input.

Comment: I see we agree now. Maybe it would improve the answer (purely from point of view of the asker), if you point out the potential difference of regex flavors which now exists between you and the asker.